# How to set numeric virtual keyboard only for LWUIT TextField that constraint with Password and Numeric?

Tags: java-me, constraints, lwuit, lwuit-textfield, lwuit-vkb

I want to set LWUIT TextField constraint to Number and Password. I make TextField by

`TextField tf=new TextField();`

`tf.setConstraints(TextArea.NUMBER|TextField.PASSWORD);`

`tf.setInputModeOrder(new String[ ] {"123"} );`

I use virtual keyboard for input to this textfield. When I press this textfiled, alphabat virtual keyboard appear and can type alphabat like a to z and other symbol.

How can I set this textfield that only appear numeric virtual keyboard?

Comment: Why you edit your question? you can ask new topic. Because I already answered for your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this for both numeric and password in the `TextField`,

```
textField.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC | TextField.PASSWORD);
textField.setInputModeOrder(new String[]{"123"});
```

Comment: This should work on non touch mobiles. But it didn't work on touch mobiles. I asked this issue in [new topic.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579142/why-numeric-constraint-didnt-work-on-virtual-keyboard-in-lwuit)

Comment: Look the answer on [my question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579142/why-numeric-constraint-didnt-work-on-virtual-keyboard-in-lwuit)