# How to open the VirtualKeyboard associated to a TextField when the field is edited?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, virtual-keyboard

I initialized the `VKBImplementationFactory` in `startApp()` :

```
public void startApp() {
        VKBImplementationFactory.init();
        Display.init(this);
        new MenuPrincipalForm(this).show();
    }
```

I created also a VirtualKeyboard in a Form :

```
...
private VirtualKeyboard vkNombre = new VirtualKeyboard();
...
vkNombre.setInputModeOrder(new String[]{VirtualKeyboard.NUMBERS_SYMBOLS_MODE});
```

And I bound this VirtualKeyboard to a TextField :

```
cintxt=new TextField();
VirtualKeyboard.bindVirtualKeyboard(cintxt, vkNombre);
```

I registered `dataChangeListener` to this TextField :

```
public class ModifierFicheClient extends Form implements ActionListener, DataChangedListener 
{
  ...
  cintxt.addDataChangeListener(this);
  ...
}
```

In the `dataChanged(int type, int index)` method I want to open the `vkNombre` VirtualKeyBoard. I know that when clicking the `TextField` then the `VirtualKeyboard` is shown automatically. But there is a case when navigating to the `TextField` through the phone mobile scroll softbuttons then I can navigate to the `TextField` without clicking it and I can type any letters ! So how to call the `VirtualKeyboard` when typing a letter on the phone mobile ?

NB : I wrote `System.out.println("zzzz");` in the `dataChanged(int type, int index)` method and the output writes two lines "zzzz" when I type `one character` ! So why the `dataChanged` method is called `two times` when I type only one letter ?

Comment: I´m not sure to understand what are you calling "the phone mobile scroll SoftButtons". Take a look here: http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/06/pimp-virtualkeyboard-by-chen-fishbein.html

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `VKBImplementationFactory.init();` in `startApp()`. Because LWUIT automatically detect whether that mobile is touch screen or not. And numeric constraint not working on `VKB` when you use LWUIT 1.5 or before versions. It is [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579142/why-numeric-constraint-didnt-work-on-virtual-keyboard-in-lwuit) on that versions. But it will be fixed on [current repository version of LWUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579142/why-numeric-constraint-didnt-work-on-virtual-keyboard-in-lwuit) (Revision: 1605).  So you can checkout from repository and use the latest LWUIT jar.

**Update:**

See the sample code for showing `VKB` while focusing on `TextField`,

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
final VirtualKeyboard keyboard = new VirtualKeyboard();
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

     public void focusGained(Component cmp) 
          keyboard.show();
     }
     public void focusLost(Component cmp) {
          keyboard.dispose();
     }
});
keyboard.setTextField(textField);
```

Comment: NO ! `VKBImplementationFactory.init();` IS ALWAYS NECESSARY IN `startApp()` !!! I TRIED TO REMOVE IT AND THE VKB IS NOT SHOWN WHEN CLICKING THE FIELD !!! KARANA TAY !!!

Comment: which version of LWUIT you are using?

Comment: the version of LWUIT I use is 1.4

Comment: that version you need to use `VKBImplementationFactory.init()`. Why you dont try with latest version?

Comment: Does the latest version can answer my need ? That is : how to show the VKB when I edit a TextField without clicking it ?

Comment: LWUIT latest resolve some bugs like numeric constraint in `VKB`. If you need always open `VKB`, Just see my update in my answer and it just sample. you need modify for your needs.